# Macro to prompt user to select CSV files for import into existing sheet in workbook

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am running a macro which automatically takes csv files and import them into specific worksheets in my workbook. However, I would want to add greater flexibility by having the user select the files for import rather than have the macro automatically grab the csv files because the naming could change as well as the directory. I am new to VBA and have been trying to better understand the MsoFileDialogType and GetOpenFilename but having difficulty trying to grasp the concept/implementation into my code.

What I ultimately want is for the user to click a button on the workbook front-end. Be prompted with a message to select the first csv file for import. This csv file will be imported into a pre-named worksheet in the workbook temp1. However since the data files come in pairs, I want the user to be able to select the next csv file after the first one into temp2.

What I have currently is:

```
Worksheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = "temp1"
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;MAC Directory path here" _
        , Destination:=Range("A1"))
        .Name = "temp 1 03.02.12"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = xlMacintosh
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1, 1)
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .UseListObject = False
End With
ActiveSheet.Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps something on these lines.

```
Sub GetCSVList()
Dim dlgOpen As FileDialog
Set dlgOpen = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With dlgOpen
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    ''Start in
    .InitialFileName = "Z:\docs\"
    .Show
End With

For Each fname In dlgOpen.SelectedItems
    ImportCSV fname
Next
End Sub

Sub ImportCSV(fname)
Set ws = Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
ws.Name = "temp" & Worksheets.Count + 1

With ws.QueryTables.Add( _
        Connection:="TEXT;" & fname, _
        Destination:=Range("A1"))
    .Name = "Temp" & Worksheets.Count + 1
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = xlMacintosh
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    '.UseListObject = False
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Remou, I tried implementing the code but encountered this error: "User-defined type not defined" and highlighted this line -> Dim dlgOpen As FileDialog

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using? Can you add a reference to the Microsoft Office x.x Object Library?

Comment: Hi Remou, I am using Mac Office 2011. I went under Tools -> References, and made sure Visual Basic for Applications, Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library, and Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library were checked.

Comment: The Mac version may be quite different, you may wish to read http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macexcel/multiple-selections-in-file-dialog/dc781583-8ab8-44e8-a9a5-9f20c1c9b8b5?msgId=bc1da6c6-25cd-4677-ae67-8c2c8efbbd45. However, feeding the name into the CSV import should be fairly similar even on a MAC.